# Should I tell the instructor that I will miss the next class?

Tags: graduate-school, professorship, coursework, attendance

I have an interview scheduled at the same time as a class, and I'm wondering if I should tell the professor in advance that I won't be attending class that day. The class is important to me, but the interview is more important.

My performance in this subject is really bad, and I'm afraid that asking for an excuse will give the professor a worse impression of me.

Also, the class contains only 11 students.

Comment: If you are not expected to attend, you can tell him and ask what would be covered, so you can read it on your own.

Comment: Is your presence in the class obligatory, or is a voluntary own-responsibility kind of thing?

Comment: Before is *always* preferable.

Comment: @theforestecologist - Overedited, in my opinion.

Answer (score 30):

**It depends on the context: the class size and style.**

If it’s a graduate seminar of 8 students, then you should certainly tell the instructor.  If it is a calculus lecture of 300 students, then this will not be expected at all, and might be seen as a waste of time.  Unless of course there is a test in the class, or a record of attendance taken.

It’s hard to draw an exact line, but a good rule of thumb is perhaps: *will your absence either affect how the instructor teaches, or go on record somehow?*  If the former is the case (as in a small class with a lot of interaction), then advance warning will be appreciated by the instructor.  (If this is borderline, then it would be courteous but not necessary to let them know.) If the latter, then for the sake of your place on the record, you should give the explanation.

And of course, if the instructor has said anything specific about attendance expectations, then that trumps this general guideline!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, tell the professor about your planned absence.  Explain the situation, and ask for notes, homework, etc.

---

The additional info is helpful.  How's this:

> Subject: Planned absence
>
> Dear Prof. So-and-So,
>
> I am sorry, but a personal matter prevents me from attending class next Tuesday afternoon.
>
> I feel just terrible about this, since I have not been doing as well as I would like in [name of class] this semester.  Still, it is an unavoidable conflict, and I thought it only fair to let you know that I won't be able to attend class that day.

Ask a classmate for notes.

I didn't realize you didn't feel you were in good standing in this class -- your comment helped me understand your internal conflict over something which would normally be straightforward.

Comment: It really depends on the country of study. In some countries you're free to miss as many lectures as you wish, without notifying the professor, as long at the end you pass the exam.

Comment: But as a courtesy, it would not hurt to do as aparente001 suggests

Comment: It depends also on the size of the class. In a 300 person class, it would be strange to inform the professor (though you might tell your TA). In a 50 person class in the US, I appreciate the notice but most students don't bother to give it. In a 10 person class, it might be the norm to let the instructor know if you will be away. ALSO: asking the instructor for notes can easily come off as acting entitled and uninterested in taking responsibility for one's own learning.

Comment: The point is that my performance in this subject is really bad, asking for excuse, I think, will give him (more) bad impression about me. What to do?

Comment: _The point is that my performance in this subject is really bad_ — Then you should reschedule the interview. You really need to attend class, not because of what the instructor will think of you, but because you're struggling with the material!

Comment: @AlFagera, indicate that you are sorry to miss the class, and do your best to attend the following classes. We are all human, and it's fine to have time conflicts that prevent you from attending classes. As long as it doesn't happen too often, the instructor won't think bad of you.

Comment: @Ghost This very much depends on the context... If I (in France) had gone to see a prof and told him/her that I would be absent at the next session, I would have met a blank stare and/or a shrug. It wouldn't have been courteous, it would have been a waste of time for both of us.

Comment: @JeffE, I don't think I can easily change the interview; despite the importance of the class for me. Furthermore, we are (for those wondering about the class size) 11 students only, I'm in graduate school in KSA. Thanks for all.

Comment: @svavil: "it's fine to have time conflicts that prevent you from attending classes" - this depends a lot on the context. Various universities I am familiar with require students to consider university the first priority. Basically, having a job interview is not a valid reason to miss a class, and while most teaching staff will probably be lenient if it doesn't happen too often for classes with obligatory attendance, "it's fine" is certainly not the correct description in this context.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I agree. My point of view was possibly an impression from my professors and peers considering job search an equally important endeavor, but this is strongly culture-dependent.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper In my background (as a student and the lead instructor of a college department) the point of colleges is to prepare students for what lies ahead after the college world.  If a student had a job interview, conflicting with the class would be unfortunate.  However, landing the job successfully would be far more worthwhile than coming to a class and helping to further prepare for getting that job.  It seems we may have been exposed to some different backgrounds/attitudes.

Comment: This advice is very incomplete, and there are numerous cases when it should not be followed.

Comment: @TOOGAM: Sure, various factors can play into this. While in my place, universities too convey professional skills for future occupations, I also see a certain opposition by universities to be perceived as "factories for workers", rather than also being institutions to provide education as a value of its own. Furthermore, the final six months of studies during which students often only write a thesis and have no classes at all should be plenty of time for scheduling job interviews. Also, scheduling itself is seen as an important skill for the students' future lives, and that includes ...

Comment: ... the skill to schedule an occasional one-time event such as a job interview in a way such that there is no collision with a (usually quite sparse!) university timetable. Lastly, it certainly is simpler to draw a line by accepting no external appointments instead of starting to distinguish job interviews from practice workdays, open house days at one's future employer, assessment days, etc., and thereby converting the expectation of prioritizing university in general into a joke due to the number of exceptions.  For deeper reflections on this, a separate question might be warranted, though.

Comment: In addition to the other reasons this advice is at best situation dependent, it's not always appropriate to ask the professor for notes and the homework.  That's turning your absence into the professor's problem by making more work.  In many cases you should make alternate plans to find out what happened in the class (say, by getting notes from another student); in that case, if you're informing the professor, you should also point out that you're taking those steps to demonstrate that you're proactively trying to make up for the missed without asking for extra help from the professor.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Tangentially this has an annoying side effect: talkers, sleepers, generally anyone rude (to lecturer) and annoying (to those that want to be there) in attendance for no reason other than perhaps a misguided feeling of being required.. Honestly several times I've witnessed it so bad that I want to leave myself, out of embarrassment/guilt by association.

Comment: @OllieFord: Where "this" refers to required attendance, I presume (I was only indirectly talking about that here; my comments focused on why or why not to consider a job interview a valid reason to not attend a class, whether or not attendance is required)? Indeed, whether or not attendance is required for the OP does not get clear from the question; I have already [asked about it in a comment](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/57903/should-i-tell-the-instructor-that-i-will-miss-the-next-class/57904?noredirect=1#comment135634_57903).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Apologies, I fell victim to an unexpanded comment thread. I referred to your first comment and lecture attendance as a "first priority". In my neck of the woods, exams are a priority, and anything else take it or leave it. As my angry comment above (sorry, long day) alludes to, I'd rather more left it.

Comment: Drop the "sorry" and the "I feel terrible" stuff. You're not doing anything wrong that harms the professor, so there's no need to apologize. It's enough to say, "I would never blithely miss class..." or something of that sort.

Comment: @transitionsynthesis - I agree, in general -- but I wanted to draft something OP would be comfortable with ("My performance in this subject is really bad, and I'm afraid that asking for an excuse will give the professor a worse impression of me").